# Connecting flights on international travel. What should I expect?

Tags: usa, luggage, airport-security, united-airlines, connecting-flights

I will be making my first trip to the United States soon, and would like to know ahead of time what the process will be like both arriving and departing, to be prepared and save time.

I'm flying TLV->SFO->LAX and LAX->EWR->TLV, with United.

1. Will I need to collect my baggage between connections?
2. Do I need to go through security again in the connections?
3. Should I simply follow the connecting flights signs in both airports during the layover? Or do I need to notice anything specific because of the domestic->international hop?

Thanks!

Comment: Single ticket for each leg or the same ticket for the whole journey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entering the USA in SFO, you will go through passport control, then collect your bags and go through customs. If the bags were checked through to LAX, you will next drop your bags at the next station and then exit the secured area, go back through TSA security and go to your next gate. If the bags were not checked through, I believe you will need to carry the bags out to the next airline's ticket counter to re-check the bags before going through security.

Unlike many other countries, in the USA, you will always go through customs at your first airport of entry, unless there is an arrangement to go through US customs before the foreign departure. As far as I know, this is only done in Canada.

On the return flight, assuming your bags are checked through to TLV, you'll check them in LAX and not handle them again until your destination.

Comment: "Unlike many other countries, in the USA, you will always go through customs at your first airport of entry" For an international to domestic flight, this is the case everywhere except in Europe.

Comment: > As far as I know, this is only done in Canada. - and Ireland and ... https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance

Comment: @chx and the Caribbean and the **UAE**! Canada and the Caribbean I can understand but Ireland and the UAE are just out there. Learn something new every day!